# How to report unpushed commits to a new created branche

Tags: git

I want to report (commit and push) some local commits (4 in my case) to a newly created branch, without having to push them to the master.

[image: Git schema]

In the schema :
 - a, b, c and d are pushed commits
 - c1, c2, c3 and c4 are unpushed commits
 - x means the creation of the branch new-branch

My aim is to report commits c1, c2, c3 and c4 to new-branch locally and then push them to the remote repository.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your schema is weird. Please distinguish between commits and branches. What is `branch-x`? a branch? If so, what is `branche`? Also : what is `local`? A branch? if not, what is local here? Please clarify all this.

Comment: In fact, it is weird: a ... d, commit1... commit4 are commits,  branch-x is a branch which is created from the master branch when it was in the state c (commit c pushed)

Comment: What do you mean by "report"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want to have the content of commit1 ... commit4 into my branche locally so I can commit/push them to the repository

Comment: If they are commits, they are already in the repository. They are probably also already part of a branch, otherwise you wouldn't see them.

Comment: @mkrieger1: my question wasn't clear enough, c1..c4 are local commits (local repo) I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Seems like you only need to use `git checkout -b new-branch c4` and then `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

Each commit has a SHA assigned to it, which is a "long" hex value, for example:

```
d6cd1e2bd19e03a81132a23b2025920577f84e37
```

You could see the SHA of each commit in your history by running the below command on the respective branch:

```
git log
```

To solve your issue, which by the way lacks details, you could switch to `branch-x` from a command prompt and then `cherry-pick` each of the 4 commits. Like this:

```
git checkout branch-x
git cherry-pick <commit-1 SHA>
git cherry-pick <commit-2 SHA>
git cherry-pick <commit-3 SHA>
git cherry-pick <commit-4 SHA>
```

Comment: Nowadays you can provide more than one commit in `git cherry-pick`. Also, you don't needs SHA-1 identifiers, you can use for other ways to refer to revisions, like for example `master..` or `HEAD~4..HEAD`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to **move** commits `<commit1>` to `<commit4>` to branch 'branch-x', you can use **[`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)** for that, or to be more exact:

```
$ git rebase --onto branch-x master
```

Here 'branch-x' is the branch you want to "move" commits to, and 'master' is from where you branched from creating 'local' branch.

If you want to **copy** commits, then you can use `git cherry-pick` like in [Khalil Khalaf answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59396203/46058).